# SQL - Getting more data with a GROUP BY

Tags: sql

Hoping someone can help me out with this.

Lets say I have a table called incoming_data with 4 columns:

```
primary_key_id
serial_number
counter
selected_color
```

I get data from a source that fills this table. The primary key has its identity 
turned on so it is not repeating. I will get duplicate serial numbers with different selected colors.

The counter is ever increasing coming from the device.

So what I want to do is select all the data I received today, group the data by serial number and only get the record
with the highest counter value.

Simple:

```
SELECT      serial_number, MAX(counter)
FROM        incoming_data 
GROUP BY    serial number
```

This works perfectly, except that I want to do something with the color information 
that I received.

If I add color to the select, then I get ALL the records since all
the colors I received that day are different. That wont work.

If I could get the primary_key_id of the record then I could just 
query for the color but this doesn't work either since each primary_key_id 
value is different I get them all.

Any suggestions on a better technique for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the relevant key, then join back to get "non key".
This works in MS SQL Server and later Sybase.

```
SELECT 
    i.serial_number, i.counter, i.selected_color
FROM
   (
   SELECT      serial_number, MAX(counter) AS maxc
   FROM            incoming_data 
   GROUP BY    serial number
   ) max
   JOIN
   incoming_data i ON max.serial_number = i.serial_number AND max.maxc = i.counter
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: t odeal with cases where multiple records have same serial number and max counter value.. This will extract the one of those multiples with the biggest primary_key_id

```
   Select * From incoming_data 
    Where primary_key_id In 
       (Select Max(primary_key_id) From incoming_data I
        Where Counter = 
              (Select Max(counter) From incoming_data 
               Where SerialNumber = I.SerialNumber)
        Group By SerialNumber)
```

Comment: If there is a duplicate counter , lets say two devices counters were 500 in the same day, would this cause a problem since we are matching the counters? It is very possible that the counters from multiple different devices will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this might do what you want?

`SELECT      selected_color, serial_number, counter
FROM            incoming_data 
GROUP BY    serial_number
ORDER BY counter DESC
LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the exact color from the query, but could parse it afterwards, try this:

```
SELECT      serial_number, MAX(counter), MAX( CONCAT(counter, ':', selected_color) )
FROM            incoming_data 
GROUP BY    serial number
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get the max numbers from two joined tables.  I tried to use DISTINCT to avoid repeatative numbers, but failed.  Then I found the following query and works perfect on single table, but I failed to have it worked on joined two tables.

How to implement the following query on my query:
select top 10 ConsumptionKWH
from PeriodicConsumptions
group by ConsumptionKWH
order by min(ConsumptionKWH) asc

Needed on:

" SELECT * FROM " & _
                       " (SELECT Distinct top 10 " & _
                       " PeriodicConsumptions.ConsumptionKWH, " & _
                       " MeterReadings.MeterNo, " & _
                       " MeterReadings.LastKWH," & _
                       " MeterReadings.AccountNo, " & _
                       " MeterReadings.MultiplyFactor," & _
                       " MeterReadings.LastReading, " & _
                       " MeterReadings.ThisMonthReading," & _
                       " MeterReadings.NumberofDays," & _
                       " MeterReadings.ReadingGYear, " & _
                       " MeterReadings.ReadingGMonth, " & _
                       " MeterReadings.ReadingDate " & _
                       " FROM MeterReadings,  PeriodicConsumptions" & _
                       " Where MeterReadings.AccountNo = PeriodicConsumptions.AccountNo " & _
                       " and MeterReadings.ReadingGYear =PeriodicConsumptions.ConsumptionYear " & _
                       " and MeterReadings.ReadingGMonth =PeriodicConsumptions.ConsumptionMonth " & _
                       " and MeterReadings.ReadingDate = PeriodicConsumptions.FromDate " & _
                       " ORDER BY  PeriodicConsumptions.ConsumptionKWH desc) as t " & _
                       " ORDER BY ConsumptionKWH asc"

Thanks